# mysql query returning different dates

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add a new feature to my weather station, date of highest temperature and the date it rained the most.

Why do does this code give different dates in the result?

If I changed the first query to either T, R, P or H, the maximum for the row are shown but the date is always the same.
Once I understand that, I may be able to fix other problems with the code.

[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMVMl.png)

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"
    SELECT DateTime,max(Tmax)
    FROM alldata        
    WHERE YEAR(DateTime) = YEAR(NOW())      

    "
);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $maxtempDate1 = $row['DateTime'];
            $tempMax1 = $row['max(Tmax)'];  
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"
    SELECT DateTime,Tmax
    FROM alldata 
    WHERE Tmax=(select max(Tmax) from alldata)
    AND YEAR(DateTime) = YEAR(NOW())        
    "
);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $maxtempDate = $row['DateTime'];
            $tempMax = $row['Tmax'];

}
```

Comment: I would of thought AND YEAR(DateTime) = YEAR(NOW()) would also show just this year.

Comment: So, do you understand what's wrong now?

Comment: No not really. The second query gives the correct result.

Comment: Well, perhaps the first thing to appreciate is that aggregate functions generally require a GROUP BY clause. Also, consider what would happen if instead of using MAX, you simply ORDERED the data by tmax and (in the event of a tie) date

Comment: I will read up on GROUP BY and try again in a few hours.  I will try ORDERED as well. Thanks

Comment: I added ORDER BY Tmax ASC

Comment: I followed your advice and it works. I used ORDER BY Tmax I had not used that before. I can now experiment with the rest of the PHP code. Thanks

Comment: I would assume that you'd want DESC, but whatever.

Comment: Not enough points to chat.. DESC returned a result of 0.0 Not sure but it looks like $row['Tmax'] gets the last entry so ASC worked. Will work out how to use DESC and grab to first result (highest number) later. Thanks again. LIMIT 1 must work

Answer (score 0):

$result = mysqli_query($con,"
        SELECT DateTime,Tmax
        FROM alldata
        WHERE YEAR(DateTime) = YEAR(NOW())
        ORDER BY Tmax DESC
        LIMIT 1 
        "
    );
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $maxtempDate = $row['DateTime'];
                $tempMax = $row['Tmax'];

```
}
```